# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, debezium-server

I am running kafka and debezium PostgreSQL connector locally on Windows. everything else is good, topics are also stored. just getting this error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \tmp\connect.offsets
```

All the steps I followed:

Running Zookeeper:

```
 .\kafka\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\kafka\config\zookeeper.properties
```

Running Kafka:

```
.\kafka\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\kafka\config\server.properties
```

Running Connector With **postgres-connector.properties** file:

```
.\kafka\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\kafka\config\connect-standalone.properties .\kafka\postgres-connector.properties
```

postgres-connector.properties file

```
name=my-postgres-connector
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
database.hostname=localhost
database.port=5432
database.user=postgres
database.password=1524
database.dbname=MartenDB
database.server.name=postgres
table.include.list=public.student
plugin.name=pgoutput
topic.prefix=sid
slot.name=connector1_replication_slot
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the `connect-standalone.properties` to use proper Windows filepaths, not `/tmp` for the offsets file.

You should also use `connect-distributed.sh` instead, which will use Kafka topics, not files for offset storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the question is, What will be the path on Windows? Currently, I'm in the testing phase, which is why Im using standalone mode.

Comment: You can test with distributed mode too. The path doesn't matter. It just needs to be one that exists and the process has read/write access to... Your current error says the path \tmp doesn't exist, which is true, because you're missing a drive letter, for example